# Calculate Average of list using recursion in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, recursion, average

I need a function called average(a), where a is a list, and it returns the average of the elements using recursion. I solved it with an auxiliary function called sum (which solves recursively the sum of all elements of a list), but I want to solve it within the average function.
This is what I have tried:

```
def average(a):  
    if len(a)==1:  
        return a[0]  
    else:  
        return (a[0]+average(a[1:]))/len(a)  

print(average([1,2,3]))
```

It should return 2.0 in this case.
The issue here is that when I call the function in the return I'm dividing again for `len(a)`. Thats not right.

Comment: It's nice to want things but this is not a free coding service. Make a legitimate attempt and come back when you run into a specific issue that can't be solved by debugging and Googling.

Comment: def promedio(a):
    if len(a)==1:
        return a[0]
    else:
        return (a[0]+promedio(a[1:]))/len(a)
print(promedio([1,2,3]))

This is my attempt, I know that the problem is that im not dividing the final result, im dividing within the division, but dont know how to solve it.

Im sorry im new at this, dont know how to format my code!

Comment: Edit your question to contain all relevant information and nominate for reopening.

Comment: You can't format a comment and you shouldn't post code in comments anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pool two or more averages, you need to apply convex weighting based on how much data each is based on.  In your case:

```
def average(a):  
    if len(a) == 1:  
        return a[0]  
    else:  
        n = len(a)
        return (a[0] + (n - 1) * average(a[1:])) / n  

print(average([1,2,3]))
```

gives weights `1/n` and `(n-1)/n` to the individual element and the average of the rest, respectively.

A more scalable solution works with half-lists rather than whittling the problem down one-by-one.

```
def average(a):
    n = len(a) 
    if n == 1:  
        return a[0]  
    else:  
        mid = n // 2
        return (mid * average(a[:mid]) + (n - mid) * average(a[mid:])) / n  

print(average([1,2,3]))
```

That dramatically cuts the resource requirements, making the recursive stack O(log n) rather than O(n) and reducing the additional storage needed for intermediate sublists.

Both of these will work for small lists, with the second able to deal with problems where the first breaks down due to stack overflow.  However, an iterative solution would make more sense than recursion for this task.